# Tracking the entire editing process in spring boot

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I saw on article: https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa have "4.3. Tracking Created and Last Modified Dates" in spring boot, It's a good, but I just have a question:
Is there a way to track the entire editing process (about: old data and new data)?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try adding a listener like in here : http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/03/hibernate-using-event-listener-to-set.html - it will fetch the "old" state, or you can use PrePersist / PreRemove / PreUpdate annotations like here : https://vladmihalcea.com/prepersist-preupdate-embeddable-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: I already implement it. Just I want to see activity history user change data(It about: old and new data)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new database table to save every version of your data with the timestamp of the editing data.

Comment: Currently, I implement like: when user change data => I change status it to unactive and create new row for new data (status active). But I saw if I have any relationship with table, I need update child table, It's too complex. Are any idea for this case? Thanks

Comment: You can also create copies of your child tables. You may be interested in https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa .